# how to setup datepart set sql start date and end date

Tags: sql

i had a problem how to set up the datepart exact date that i want: hers my example Code:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
select CAST(DATEPART(wk, '01/03/2010') AS CHAR(4)).. // 01/01/2010 to 01/03/2010 to return 1
```

how can i set the datepart if  01/03/2010 to 01/09/2010 returns = 1 and 01/10/2010 to 01/16/2010 returns to 2.. up to 53 weeks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract one from the datepart:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
select CAST(DATEPART(wk, '01/03/2010') - 1 AS CHAR(4))
select CAST(DATEPART(wk, '01/09/2010') - 1 AS CHAR(4))
select CAST(DATEPART(wk, '01/10/2010') - 1 AS CHAR(4))
select CAST(DATEPART(wk, '01/16/2010') - 1 AS CHAR(4))
```

Results in:

```
1
1
2
2
```

Comment: i see.. its just simple logic.. but i can get it so easily. i spend 10 hours to solve it but i cant get it.. hayz..  thx.. littlebobbyTables